# Yammer REST API - Post to messages.json with line break

Tags: javascript, typescript, line-breaks, yammer

I'm trying to post to yammer using the REST API, and cannot seem to get a line break respected. From within Yammer, I can post an update with line breaks, so I don't understand why I can't reproduce this pro-grammatically. Has anyone run into this? Or have any ideas? Yammer seems to be double escaping the \n line break. As you can see below, I was playing with the 'is_rich_text' param but it doesn't appear to do anything unless posting an announcement.

```
const body = `${summary} \n ${url} \n line break`;

const apiUrl = `messages.json`;

return yam.platform.request({
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        'body': body,
        'is_rich_text': 'true',
        'title': title
    },
    method: 'POST',
    url: apiUrl,
    success: (data: any) => {
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop the whole `is_rich_text` property and use `\r\n` in your posts, then the line breaks will be respected.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. To include line breaks, use '\r\n'

Comment: That doesn't seem to have worked using the REST API.